# Is the Laplacian operator compact in $C_0^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I’m studying eigenvalues of the Laplacian, so I wonder if the Laplacian is a compact operator that I can apply results from spectrum theory on compact operators directly.

Here I’m taking the space of test functions $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$,where $\Omega$ can be a smooth domain
$$\Delta:f\in C_0^{\infty} \to g=\Delta f \in C_0^{\infty} $$

I’ve thought about using the Arzala-Ascoli theory to prove the compactness, but nothing came out.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the topology of the spaces that you consider?

Comment: I just realized the test function space is not normalized, I really just wanted my function to be a Banach space and invariant under Laplacian, I tried $H_0^1$ space, but it is not invariant I can’t apply the results from spectrum theories

Comment: I would expect that this is impossible

Comment: The usual way to approach this is to work with the resolvent, which is a compact operator on $L^2$ when $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes, essentially you need to decide what is the norm on the space in the first place, Probably some Lebesgue or Sobolev space. That question can only be answered once that question is settled.